# Access component methods from asyncData - nuxtjs

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxtjs, and I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to access component methods from the async data function.

For example I want to do something like this:

```
methods: {
    parseResult(data) {
        // do somthing with data...
    }
},

async asyncData({ app }) {
    const { data } = await app.$axios.get('/some/api')
    return app.parseResult(data)
},
```

Answer (score 13):

You can't. It's stated in [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/)

> You do NOT have access of the component instance through this inside
>   asyncData because it is called before initiating the component.

You could move your method into vuex store and call it from asyncdata

Comment: You could also simply move the method outside of the Vue component (just above it) and call it as a normal JS function, if it doesn't need access to the component at all.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by fredrivett in the comments, you can move your parse function outside the export default area in order to use it inside asyncData, as a normal js function:

```
<script>

let parseResult = (data) => {
        // do somthing with data...
    }

export default {
  async asyncData({ app }) {
    const { data } = await app.$axios.get('/some/api')
    return parseResult(data)
  },
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I normaly change `asyncData()` to `fetch()` and it works.